# Character movement in Pygame Zero

Tags: python, pgzero

As of right now, my character moves whilst I'm holding my key down.

e.g.

```
if keyboard.left:
   actor.x -= 5
```

However, I would like my actor to move in a sort of block-ish fashion e.g. I press my key once and it moves to the left by 5 pixels, regardless of whether I hold it down or not.

How would I do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

```
if keyboard.left: 
    move_direction = 'left'
```

and later

```
if move_direction == 'left':
    actor.x -= 5
```

and don't reset `move_direction`.

---

Eventually it may need to keep only `left` or `right` to stop moving left only when you press `right` but not when you press `top` or `bottom`.

First

```
if keyboard.left: 
    move_horizontally = 'left'

if keyboard.right: 
    move_horizontally = 'right'
```

and later

```
if move_horizontally == 'left':
    actor.x -= 5
if move_horizontally == 'right':
    actor.x += 5
```